# VBA code to run a Windows desktop shortcut from inside Word 2013

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to run a Windows desktop shortcut from inside Word 2013. I want to create a VBA macro so I can attach it to the Word Ribbon and Word keyboard commands. I want to trigger the external program with a Windows shortcut because the shortcut has a few startup switches in it.

I’ve tried to find help online, but all the solutions confuse me and many use lines and lines of code. I would think it would be a simple thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim WshShell

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run """put_path_to_your_shorcut_here"""
```

Comment: `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """put_path_to_your_shorcut_here"""` if you want a one-liner...

Answer (score 1):

Tim Williams's answer is great (I would've added a comment to it, but I don't have the points to do that), but is missing one detail.  `put_path_to_your_shorcut_here` should end in `.lnk`, the file extension for shortcuts.